# Process more than 3MP image in android

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap, crop, bitmapfactory

I want to process(crop) image having resolution with more than 3MP.

Can anybody help to resolve this issue without using `BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize` because when i used that option during loading the image in Bitmap it decreases the Pixel Value.

Comment: are you try dont using `inSampleSize`, will throw the oom or not?

Comment: @idiottiger Yes, I am getting OOM error.

Comment: well, it maybe dont have any good idea for this except `inSampleSize`

Comment: Post suggested by @HiteshPatel work well if you don't want to apply your logic for cropping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can used `Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, width,height);` if not getting OOM,
Otherwise you can used inSampleSize or you can refer to [this post](http://www.londatiga.net/featured-articles/how-to-select-and-crop-image-on-android/)

Comment: I am getting OOM error and that post you have suggested works for me, because In that we need not to apply logic for cropping.